# Days in month function only has single use

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using the following function to determine the number of days in a month:

```
function daysInMonth(month,year) { 
  return new Date(year,month,0).getDate(); 
}
```

Now when I do the following for example, it works great:

```
var currMonth = currDate.getMonth(),
    currYear = currDate.getFullYear(),
    daysInMonth = daysInMonth(currYear,currMonth+1);
```

However, if I try to use the same function again like so:

```
var test = daysInMonth(currYear,currMonth+2);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the variable daysInMonth with the value of the function daysInMonth, effectively replacing the function with an integer. Give your variable a different name and it will work e.g.

```
var currMonth = currDate.getMonth(),
currYear = currDate.getFullYear(),
numberOfDaysInMonth = daysInMonth(currYear,currMonth+1);

var test = daysInMonth(currYear,currMonth+2);
```

Comment: +1 You just beat me ;) created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQqqP/) with the solution

Comment: Aaaaah. This is probably the stupidest thing I've ever done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

function and variable name is same change function name

```
function daysInTheMonth(month,year) { 
  return new Date(year,month,0).getDate(); 
}
var test = daysInTheMonth(currYear,currMonth+2);
```